# Discord.js how do I get the "messages" property of a fetched channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to react to a chosen message by fetching messages in a fetched channel, however, I've realized that
`client.channels.fetch("id")` gets a channel, but doesn't have the same type as `msg.channel`.
`client.channels.fetch("id")` shows this description: `Discord.Channel`... but `msg.channel` shows this description:

`Message.channel: Discord.TextChannel | Discord.DMChannel | Discord.NewsChannel`
and it has the "messages" property.

Edit: it’s because I didn’t add `await`

Comment: That's because `message.channel` is guaranteed to be a channel which has messages, since you're accessing it from a message. However, `client.channels.fetch()` could return a voice channel! Who knows.

Comment: @Lioness100 so is there a way for me to specify that's it's a text channel?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: It says `Type assertion expressions can only be used in TypeScript files`

Comment: I was assuming you were using ts because of your syntax. With jsdoc you can use `/** @type {import('discord.js').TextChannel} */` over the variable declaration.

Comment: And how exactly would I put that in the code?
`client.channels.fetch("id")`, then where would that be? @Lioness100

Comment: Please look up a jsdoc tutorial